# How to change object in one sitepage?(three.js)

Tags: three.js

I want to build a gallery of 3d objects,but When i finish showing one object, how can i change it into another object by pressing ?How to delete the first object and release memorise? what knowledges should i learn?

I've tried build-and-remove iframes to display object but receive memory leak :
here is part of my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
 <HEAD>   
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">  
    <!--  
        $=function(s){return document.getElementById(s)}  
        window.onload=function(){  
            var t=[];  
            var btn1=$('btn1'),btn2=$('btn2'),btn3=$('btn3');  
            btn1.onclick=function(){  
                if($('ifm1'))return;  
                var c=$('content');  
                var ifm=document.createElement('iframe');  
                ifm.src='a.html';  
                ifm.id='ifm1';  
                c.appendChild(ifm);  
                t.push(ifm);  
            }  
            btn2.onclick=function(){  
                var ifm=$('ifm1');  
                ifm.src="";  
                ifm.parentNode.removeChild(ifm);  
            }  
        }  
    //-->  
    </SCRIPT>  
 </HEAD>  
 <BODY>  
      <input id="btn1" type="button" value="open"/>   
      <input id="btn2" type="button" value="close"/>  
      <div id="content"></div>  

 </BODY>  
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically what you want to do is to create all of your gallery objects and show just one at a time, putting all the others to `visible:false` (with use of `traverse` function). When you're finished with one object - just delete it from the scene, the same way you added it there in the first place (adding: `scene.add()`; deleting: `scene.remove()`). That way you won't have any memory leaking.

Comment: Thank you!But i have to display a large number of object with 200,000 to 300,000 faces.Browser will crash if adding too much object on it.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many faces your objects have (well, at least in your situation), since you are going to show just 1 object at a time. All of the hidden objects will not be rendered, thus they will not be taken into memory consideration, see?

Comment: I've try your metod,but my firefox crash when I add 4 jsonloader to load object...

Comment: Could you provide some jsfiddle example?